# Python strftime - date without leading 0?

Tags: python, padding, strftime

When using Python `strftime`, is there a way to remove the first 0 of the date if it's before the 10th, ie. so `01` is `1`? Can't find a `%`thingy for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 818):

Actually I had the same problem and I realized that, if you add a hyphen between the `%` and the letter, you can remove the leading zero.

For example `%Y/%-m/%-d`:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2).strftime("%Y/%-m/%-d")
'2023/1/2'
```

This only works on Unix (Linux, OS X), not Windows (including Cygwin).  On Windows, you would use `#`, e.g. `%Y/%#m/%#d`.

Comment: Doesn't even work for me, gives a ValueError (windows, python 2.6)

Comment: Works for me, linux python2.6! +1s for Ryan and Cory!

Comment: It worked for me on OS X, but I'm using the Python 2.7.2 from python.org.

Comment: Worked for me, both on OSX and Linux (debian)

Comment: Works in OS X 10.8.5 with Python 2.7.2, but not in Windows 7 Pro 64-bit with Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Thanks for this great tips.. Worked like charm for Ubuntu 12.4 django-1.5

Comment: @moose I asked a question about this :-) here is the answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894172/why-does-d-or-e-remove-the-leading-space-or-zero

Comment: I get `ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%b %-d, %Y'`. OSX, Python 2.7.

Comment: `%#d` would do the same on Windows

Comment: I get ValueError, using Linux jupyter notebook

Comment: Doesn't work on alpine, which is linux, be careful since it will generate an empty string without any expectation!

Comment: Didn't know about # on Windows!

Comment: The # does not work on Win 10.0.17134 N/A version 17134 + python 3.6.0 `ValueError: '#' is a bad directive in format '%a. %#d %B %Y, %H:%M'`

Comment: Works with Ruby too.

Comment: @Doezer I encountered the same error in Windows 10 with Python 3.8.1 (`ValueError: '#' is a bad directive in format`). This error occurred when using `strptime` (`%#d` not OK) but not when using `strftime` (`%d` OK). In `strptime`, using `%d` without `#` seemed to work fine though even for parsing dates without leading zeroes.

Comment: Now that I knew what I am looking for, I found this explained in the strftime man page. It is a Glibc extension.

Comment: This works with embedded Ruby, too. Thank you!

Comment: Didn't work for me in Win10, giving error as:
ValueError: '#' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%#m-%#d %H:%M'

Comment: Hyphen trick only works on Linux. Hash trick only works on Windows. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42709606/11729954)

Answer (score 215):

We can do this sort of thing with the advent of the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) method since python2.6:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> '{dt.year}/{dt.month}/{dt.day}'.format(dt = datetime.datetime.now())
'2013/4/19'
```

Though perhaps beyond the scope of the original question, for more interesting formats, you can do stuff like:

```
>>> '{dt:%A} {dt:%B} {dt.day}, {dt.year}'.format(dt=datetime.datetime.now())
'Wednesday December 3, 2014'
```

And as of python3.6, this can be expressed as an [inline formatted string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
Python 3.6.0a2 (v3.6.0a2:378893423552, Jun 13 2016, 14:44:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> f'{dt:%A} {dt:%B} {dt.day}, {dt.year}'
'Monday August 29, 2016'
```

Comment: Very nice! Unfortunately doesn't work alone if you want to use textual representation like `time.strftime('%A %B %d, %Y')`, which yields (now, on English locale) `Tuesday October 07, 2014`.

Comment: @PekkaKlärck -- Some reason I hadn't noticed your comment until now.  It turns out that datetime specifies a very interesting `__format__` hook that allows you to write things like that.

Comment: One problem is that `'{dt.hour}'` uses a 24 hour clock :(. Using the second option still brings you back to using `'{%#I}'` on Windows and `'{%-I}'` on Unix.

Comment: Good point.  I never use 12 hour clock representations in code, so I didn't think of that case.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at this additional documentation on the format functionality: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 47):

Some platforms may support width and precision specification between `%` and the letter (such as 'd' for day of month), according to http://docs.python.org/library/time.html -- but it's definitely a non-portable solution (e.g. doesn't work on my Mac;-).  Maybe you can use a string replace (or RE, for really nasty format) after the `strftime` to remedy that? e.g.:

```
>>> y
(2009, 5, 7, 17, 17, 17, 3, 127, 1)
>>> time.strftime('%Y %m %d', y)
'2009 05 07'
>>> time.strftime('%Y %m %d', y).replace(' 0', ' ')
'2009 5 7'
```

Comment: @guneysus what do you mean? It should result in '1 January 2000'

Comment: @User The above code checks for a blank space before 0 which in case of "01 January 2000" is not present.

Answer (score 41):

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Calendar-Time.html#index-strftime-2660) is the documentation of the modifiers supported by `strftime()` in the GNU C library. (Like people said before, it might not be portable.) Of interest to you might be:

- `%e` instead of `%d` will replace leading zero in day of month with a space

Compare with the [Python documentation of `strftime() Format Codes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). `%d` is documented:

> `%d`: Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
> Examples: 01, 02, …, 31

But `%e` is not documented. Even though it is not documented, it does seem to work for me regardless (running Linux):

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1).strftime("%e")
' 1'
```

I don't know if it will work on your operating system.

Comment: %e fails for me on Windows w/ Python 2.6.  I'm guessing it's *nix specific.  Too bad :(

Comment: This is the cleanest, most general, solution---on a *nix system, at least. This works on OS X.

Comment: Like the `%-d` [above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2073189/1447415), this works in OS X 10.8.5 with Python 2.7.2, but not in Windows 7 Pro 64-bit with Python 2.7.3.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 7 SP1 with Python 3.5.1.

Comment: This introduced an extra space instead of the leading zero so if you are looking for an exact match this may not be it. 
>>> one = datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 23, 28, 48, 175214)
>>> one.strftime('%b %e %H')
'May  1 23'
>>> eleven = datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 11, 23, 28, 48, 175214)
>>> eleven.strftime('%b %e %H')
'May 11 23'

Comment: Works with modern pandas/python

Comment: Works! Combine %e with a .replace(' ','') for a solution.

Answer (score 38):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d.strftime('X%d/X%m/%Y').replace('X0','X').replace('X','')
'5/5/2011'
```

Comment: This works 01 January 2000,[Alexs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/904954/1766716) is not works.

Comment: What's the point of doing `.replace('X0','X').replace('X','')`? Just do `.replace('X0', '')` and it'll be good.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Try your suggestion on the string "X12/X12/14" and you will see.

Comment: This is hack, but it's a pythonic hack.

Answer (score 26):

On Windows, add a '#', as in '%#m/%#d/%Y %#I:%M:%S %p'

For reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx

Answer (score 25):

quite late to the party but `%-d` works on my end.

`datetime.now().strftime('%B %-d, %Y')` produces something like **"November 5, 2014"**

cheers :)

Comment: duplicate of the leading answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2073189/389812

Comment: `ValueError: Invalid format string` in my Windows system.

Comment: As stated in the [leading answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2073189/2745495), using `-` "*only works on Unix (Linux, OS X), not Windows (including Cygwin). On Windows, you would use #*"

Comment: Agreed, does not work on my windows but ok in Linux. Craziness!

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at `-` bellow:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
>>> '08-Oct-2011'
>>> datetime.now().strftime('%-d-%b-%Y')
>>> '8-Oct-2011'
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> today.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
>>> print(today)
```

Comment: Works perfectly in python 3

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Does what is asked, super simple and easy to remember. Browsing quickly through the docs I was not able to find this information.

Comment: "This should be the accepted answer". No it should not, as this only works on Linux.

Answer (score 10):

I find the Django template date formatting filter to be quick and easy. It strips out leading zeros. If you don't mind importing the Django module, check it out.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import date as django_date_filter
print django_date_filter(mydate, 'P, D M j, Y')
```

Comment: Note that if you're like me and you're not building your app in django, you'll need to tell django you don't need to configure it: `import django.conf` `django.conf.settings.configure()`

Answer (score 8):

simply use `replace` like this:

`(datetime.date.now()).strftime("%Y/%m/%d").replace("/0", "/")`

it will output:

```
'2017/7/21'
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for dates formatted like 1.4.2021 (1st of April 2021); it could catch the zero in months, but not for the days (using "01.04.2021".replace(".0",".") leads only to 01.4.2021)

Answer (score 4):

For `%d` you can convert to integer using `int()` then it'll automatically remove leading 0 and becomes integer. You can then convert back to string using `str()`.

Comment: OP question was for a solution using a format specifier in a call to strftime, rather than a roll-your-own solution involving str()

Comment: great answer, don't listen to dave hooper

Answer (score 4):

using, for example, "%-d" is not portable even between different versions of the same OS.
A better solution would be to extract the date components individually, and choose between date specific formatting operators and date attribute access for each component.

```
e = datetime.date(2014, 1, 6)
"{date:%A} {date.day} {date:%B}{date.year}".format(date=e)
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer, it will work on Windows as well as Linux.

Answer (score 4):

if we want to fetch only date without leading zero we can

```
d = date.today()
day = int(d.strftime("%d"))
```

Comment: I find this solution interesting because it works with Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Because Python really just calls the C language `strftime(3)` function on your platform, it might be that there are format characters you could use to control the leading zero; try `man strftime` and take a look. But, of course, the result will not be portable, as the Python manual will remind you. :-)

I would try using a new-style `datetime` object instead, which has attributes like `t.year` and `t.month` and `t.day`, and put those through the normal, high-powered formatting of the `%` operator, which does support control of leading zeros. See http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html for details. Better yet, use the `"".format()` operator if your Python has it and be even more modern; it has lots of format options for numbers as well. See: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Alex's method, this will work for both the start-of-string and after-spaces cases:

```
re.sub('^0|(?<= )0', '', "01 January 2000 08:00am")
```

I like this better than .format or %-d because this is cross-platform and allows me to keep using strftime (to get things like "November" and "Monday").

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but %l (lower-case L) worked for me in strftime: this may not work for everyone, though, as it's not listed in the Python documentation I found

Comment: I am using a Python-based package (weather station software called WeeWX) that only lets me specify percent-sign formatting, like this - not the complicated string-substitution stuff like most of the above answers use.

The "%l" worked for me! (on Linux)

Comment: @RobCranfill Very glad to hear this came in handy for someone! I remember it solved a rather annoying problem for me at the time

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print now.strftime("%b %_d")
```

Comment: This replaces the leading zero with a space, which is not what the OP asked for

Comment: `ValueError: '_' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %_d %H:%M:%S %Y'` using python 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.6+:

```py
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
text = "Today it is " + today.strftime(f"%A %B {today.day}, %Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late, but a simple list slicing will do the work

```
today_date = date.today().strftime('%d %b %Y')
if today_date[0] == '0':
    today_date = today_date[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard library is good enough for most cases but for a really detailed manipulation with dates you should always look for some specialized third-party library.

Using [Arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```py
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.utcnow().format('dddd, D. M. YYYY')
'Friday, 6. 5. 2022'
```

Look at the full [list of supported tokens](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#supported-tokens).

Answer (score 0):

A little bit tricky but works for me

ex. from `2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z` to `2021-02-1`

```
from datetime import datetime

dateObj = datetime.strptime('2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
dateObj.strftime('%Y-%m-{}').format(dateObj.day)
```

Answer (score 0):

An amateur approach to remove '0' prefix for Day & Month, by casting to 'int'

```
dt = "08/01/2023"
dtArr = d.split("/")
print(str(int(x[0]))+'/'+str(int(x[1]))+'/'+str(int(x[2])))
```