# Get rid of leading zeros for date strings in Python?

Tags: python, date, leading-zero

Is there a nimble way to get rid of leading zeros for date strings in Python?

In the example below I'd like to get 12/1/2009 in return instead of 12/01/2009. I guess I could use regular expressions. But to me that seems like overkill. Is there a better solution?

```
>>> time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y',time.strptime('12/1/2009', '%m/%d/%Y'))
'12/01/2009'
```

#### See also

> [Python strftime - date without leading 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904928/python-strftime-date-without-leading-0)

Comment: The script that this is intended for spits out very nicely formatted pdfs, and I think it's not that visually appealing with the leading zeros. Not exactly a show stopper, but I'd love to figure out a quick way to avoid them...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@OP, it doesn't take much to do a bit of string manipulation.

```
>>> t=time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y',time.strptime('12/1/2009', '%m/%d/%Y'))
>>> '/'.join( map( str, map(int,t.split("/")) ) )
'12/1/2009'
```

Comment: There is now a better solution with Python 3: ```datetime.strptime("05/13/1999", "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%m/%-d/%Y")```

Answer (score 22):

A simpler and readable solution is to format it yourself:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> "%d/%d/%d"%(d.month, d.day, d.year)
4/8/2012
```

Comment: took me ages to find the answer to this particular problem. I'm having to pass my date to the `date` class, and it only accepts `date(d,m,yyyy)` not `date(dd,mm,yyyy)`

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest a very simple regular expression. It's not like this is performace-critical, is it?

Search for `\b0` and replace with nothing.

I. e.:

```
import re
newstring = re.sub(r"\b0","",time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y',time.strptime('12/1/2009', '%m/%d/%Y')))
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I have in place, but as I said in the initial post, I just think it's a bit overkill to use re for such a trivial thing...

Comment: Well, you could `split` the string, `lstrip` the zeroes, and re-`join` the string, but that's probably much harder to read.

Comment: This is what I ended up with, it results in the cleanest code in my opinion. I'm still shocked that this is so nontrivial though!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> time.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y',time.strptime('8/1/2009', '%m/%d/%Y'))
'8/1/2009'
```

However, I suspect this is dependent on the system's `strftime()` implementation and might not be fully portable to all platforms, if that matters to you.

Comment: Yeah, it does depend on the system's strftime. Doesn't work on Python2.6.1+WinXP for example