# Remove leading 0's for str(date)

Tags: python

If I have a datetime object, how would I get the date as a string in the following format:

```
1/27/1982  # it cannot be 01/27/1982 as there can't be leading 0's
```

The current way I'm doing it is doing a .replace for all the digits (01, 02, 03, etc...) but this seems very inefficient and cumbersome. What would be a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2309828/113527

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could format it yourself instead of using `strftime`:

```
'{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(d.month, d.day, d.year) // Python 2.6+

'%d/%d/%d' % (d.month, d.day, d.year)
```

Comment: I think it would be nicer as: `'{0.month}/{0.day}/{0.year}'.format(d)`

Comment: FWIW the OP seems to require month first.

Comment: @Jeff: Agreed, that's pretty good.

Comment: @John: Ah yes, looks like. In general I'd strongly advise against using this date format for exactly this reason, locale-dependent confusion. Please use the ISO 8601 format (`%Y-%m-%d`) wherever possible as it is the only unambiguous ordering.

Comment: @bobince: Absolutely! YYYY-MM-DD makes sense. Even DD-MM-YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY isn't too silly, though it makes useful sorting harder. But M/D/YYYY which the Americans use is just plain illogical.

Comment: @Jeff: Why not put that as an answer?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: I was but bobince had already beat me to it.  My solution was practically the same as his so there's no point in duplicating it.

Comment: @Jeff: it's enough different that I think it's worth a separate answer. Then you get more votes, too (though being over 10k you perhaps don't care?)

Answer (score 1):

The datetime object has a method strftime(). This would give you more flexibility to use the in-built format strings.

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior.

I have used `lstrip('0')` to remove the leading zero.

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime(1982, 1, 27)

>>> d.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
'01/27/82'

>>> d.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
'01/27/1982'

>>> d.strftime("%m/%d/%Y").lstrip('0')
'1/27/1982'
```

Comment: This wouldn't work in a year like on the days though, on a day like 05.