# removing entries in a column of data, python

Tags: python

I have an excel spread sheet of data for which i am opening in python. The spreadsheet has a heading and all the data values in each column, e.g.

```
Time
00:07
00:15
...
```

I have opened the file and split it into columns (each with a heading and the data below):

```
for line in open ('name_of_file'):
    column = line.split(',')
    time = column[0].split(',')
    print(time[0])
```

this prints out a list such as:

```
Time
00
01
02
```

I was wondering whether there is a way of removing the first entry in these printed columns?

Comment: The two time lists (in the question above) are in columns

Comment: FOR THE LOVE OF ALL THAT IS HOLY, DO NOT REIMPLEMENT CSV PARSING BY HAND! WE HAVE [A MODULE FOR THAT](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)! ... Sorry, got a little carried away there.

Comment: Also, you are splitting a line by `,`, then expecting that any of the resulting values will contain `,`. That's not going to happen (unless you're using `csv` to parse and a column contains quoted commas or somesuch). You'd need to provide sample input data to work with here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove leading 0's for str(date)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618863/remove-leading-0s-for-strdate)

Comment: Thank you all, that makes it a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `csv` module to help you along, and then skip the first line:

```
import csv

with open('name_of_file') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # skips the first line, the header
    for row in reader:
       print(row[0]) # The first column
```