# time.strptime changing output formatting

Tags: python, time, strptime

I'm trying to change default output formatting of strptime and datetime in my functions:

```
   def start_week_date(year, week):
        format_string = "%i %i 1" % (int(year),int(week))
        start = time.strptime(format_string, '%Y %W %w')
        print datetime.date(start.tm_year, start.tm_mon, start.tm_mday)
        return datetime.date(start.tm_year, start.tm_mon, start.tm_mday)
```

output of which is being passed to another one:

```
for date_oncall in date_range(start_week_date(year,week), start_week_date(year,week+1)):
    print date_oncall

def date_range(start_date, end_date):
    """Generator of dates in between"""
    if start_date > end_date:
        raise ValueError("Start date is before end date.")
    while True:
        yield start_date
        start_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        if start_date >= end_date:
            break
```

Is there an elegant way to change default formatting so if day of a month or a month is < 10 it doesn't get the '0' at the beginning?
Basically instead of '03-05-2012' I would like to get '3-5-2012'.

Thanks much in advance for any suggestions.

Regards,
Jakub

Comment: Looks like this should answer your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309828/get-rid-of-leading-zeros-for-date-strings-in-python

Comment: Hi Dan,
Thanks for your hint - I didn't find that thread before. J.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`date` objects have a method, `strftime`, to manually specify the format, but it doesn't have an option to do what you want - so, that means you need to construct the string yourself from the other attributes of `date_oncall`. The good news is that this is quite easy:

```
>>> '{d.day}-{d.month}-{d.year}'.format(d=date_oncall)
'17-1-2010'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for - thank you ! C[_] (virtual cup of coffee for you :) )
Could you please explain what's happening when you construct that string? I can't quite figure this out what's the difference between '{0}'.format(date_oncall) and your way.

Comment: It is equivalent to `{}-{}-{}.format(date_oncall.day, date_oncall.month, date_oncall.year)`. The format minilanguage lets you put the attribute lookup into the string itself, which is helpful for clarity in cases like this. The keyword argument (`d=date_oncall`) just lets us use a name for the object inside the string - `{.day}-{.month}-{.year}` is fine, but needs to be given the same date three times, since the three `{}` use successive positional arguments. So, you need `{0.day}-{0.month}-{0.year}` , but as that point you might as well use the keyword argument.

Comment: Thanks again lvc - I wasn't aware that strftime has the attributes you  listed above. I read time documentation and it became clearer.
Cheers,
J.

Answer (score 0):

check this link:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm

by using

```
time.strftime(string[, format])
```

you can specify the day of the month format without the '0' at the beginning, by using '%e'.

Comment: `%e` doesn't appear to be available for strftime: `date_oncall.strftime('%e')` gives a `ValueError`.