# Python datetime formatting without zero-padding

Tags: python, datetime, formatting, zero-pad

Is there a format for printing Python datetimes that won't use zero-padding on dates and times?

Format I'm using now:

```
mydatetime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p')
```

**Result:** 02/29/2012 05:03PM
**Desired:** 2/29/2012 5:03PM

What format would represent the month as '2' instead of '02', and time as '5:03PM' instead of '05:03PM'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python strftime - date without leading 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904928/python-strftime-date-without-leading-0)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The formatting options available with `datetime.strftime()` will all zero-pad.  You could of course roll you own formatting function, but the easiest solution in this case might be to post-process the result of `datetime.strftime()`:

```
s = mydatetime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p').lstrip("0").replace(" 0", " ")
```

Comment: Sven- Because I want to look like Facebook. Thanks!

Comment: This is useful. I needed to create URLs with non-padded days, and had to string 3 of these together: dt.strftime("%B_")+dt.strftime("%d").lstrip("0")+dt.strftim\
e(",_%Y")

Comment: Very few people use zero-padded hours in North America when writing the time by hand.

Comment: Won't this still zero pad the day of the month?

Comment: @JudgeMaygarden: That's why the solution does `.lstrip("0")` to get rid of the leading zero.

Comment: This is the only answer that works as advertised on Windows to get a naturalized time output, but I wish there was a better way.

Comment: Some tools, e.g. AWS CloudWatch Logs, do not work well with non-zero-padded timestamps.

Comment: Just adding a note that "%e" instead of "%d" for the day of the month will space pad the single-digit days. That is not generally useful so it makes more sense to do the .replace(" 0"," ") approach with "%d".

Comment: Why I want to remove pad zeroes? Because this is wrong by [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html), for example in podcast feed.

Answer (score 265):

The other alternate to avoid the "all or none" leading zero aspect above is to place a minus in front of the field type:

```
mydatetime.strftime('%-m/%d/%Y %-I:%M%p')
```

Then this: '4/10/2015 03:00AM'

Becomes: '4/10/2015 3:00AM'

You can optionally place a minus in front of the day if desired.

Edit: The minus feature derives from the GNU C library (“glibc”) as mentioned in the [Linux strftime manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) under “Glibc notes”

Comment: Great answer, but Linux only. Won't work on Windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807164/python-time-formatting-different-in-windows

Comment: Why does this work? I can't find a reference to this in the docs for `date.__format__` or `time.strftime`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.__format__, and https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html#time.strftime respectively

Comment: @Amin Shah Gilani, this is a Linux derived alternative, I’ve updated the post to link to this implementation specific feature’s origin.

Comment: see below for windows solution

Answer (score 117):

The new string formatting system provides an alternative to `strftime`. It's quite readable -- indeed, it might be preferable to `strftime` on that account. Not to mention the fact that it doesn't zero-pad:

```
>>> '{d.month}/{d.day}/{d.year}'.format(d=datetime.datetime.now())
'3/1/2012'
```

Since you probably want zero padding in the minute field, you could do this:

```
>>> '{d.month}/{d.day}/{d.year} {d.hour}:{d.minute:02}'.format(d=now)
'3/1/2012 20:00'
```

If you want "regular" time instead of "military" time, you can still use the standard `strftime` specifiers as well. Conveniently, for our purposes, `strftime` *does* provide a code for the 12-hour time padded with a blank instead of a leading zero:

```
'{d.month}/{d.day}/{d.year} {d:%l}:{d.minute:02}{d:%p}'.format(d=now)
'4/4/2014  6:00PM'
```

This becomes somewhat less readable, alas. And as @mlissner points out, `strftime` will fail on some (all?) platforms for dates before 1900.

Comment: It has been around since python 2.6. (It's not _that_ new.)

Comment: To spell out the month, for example, you can use the following: `"{0.day} {0:%B %Y}".format(d)` which would give you `'2 August 2013'` as the day of this comment :)

Comment: This is interesting, but it doesn't actually answer OP, because he wants AM/PM hours. I'm not actually going to downvote it, but the accepted answer is actually right if you are trying to get "American" date/time formatting in python.

Comment: Note that this technique uses strftime, which will fail on dates prior to 1900. If you have old dates, you'll regret this.

Comment: @mlissner, "this technique" => "the last technique" -- the first two don't use `strftime`.

Comment: @senderle Good point. It's surprising through, since strftime itself is not in sight.

Comment: @mlissner, yes, I can see how that might be surprising. The `datetime` object's `__format__` method is basically an alias of [datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__format__). So that's two layers of implicit behavior; the implicit call to `datetime.__format__` and the fact that `__format__` is an alias in this case. This might be one of those "practicality beats purity" moments.

Comment: fak! I just realized where I didn't point d to another object, I just passed it as a positional arg.

Answer (score 91):

Accepted answer not a proper solution (IMHO) The proper documented methods:

In Linux "#" is replaced by "-":

%-d, %-H, %-I, %-j, %-m, %-M, %-S, %-U, %-w, %-W, %-y, %-Y

In Windows "-" is replaced by "#":

%#d, %#H, %#I, %#j, %#m, %#M, %#S, %#U, %#w, %#W, %#y, %#Y

```
#Linux
mydatetime.strftime('%-m/%d/%Y %-I:%M%p')

# Windows
mydatetime.strftime('%#m/%d/%Y %#I:%M%p')
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx

As stated by Sagneta: The # hash trick on Windows is only available to native python executable. this will not work for cygwin-based python implementations.

Comment: This is correct. Due note however that the # hash trick on Windows is only available to native python executables. In other words, this will not work for cygwin-based python implementations.

Comment: Wow this great to know but I'm horrified of the consequence.  I'm testing date formatting returned from a Database and I need to pass in the expected formatting for each test and this adds tons of complexity.

Answer (score 23):

Good answer [from Chris Freeman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29980406/4518341) on Linux.

On windows, it's:

```
mydate.strftime('%#m/%#d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by several others, to ignore leading zero on windows, you must use `%#d` instead of `%-d`.

For those who like to write clean cross platform python code, without seeing platform switches in business logic, here is a `Python3` helper that enables you to have one format string for both Windows, Linux and Others (tested Linux, Windows and FreeBSD):

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

def dateToStr(d: datetime, fmt: str) -> str:
    return d.strftime(fmt.replace('%-', '%#') if os.name == 'nt' else fmt)

dateToStr(datetime.now(), '%-m/%-d/%-Y')
```

On a side note, this is another one of those `Whaaaaaaaat?` features in Python. I don't understand why they did not create a standard format set for all platforms and add an optional 'use_native' flag to use native platform features. Guess it was an early design decision that must be kept for legacy support.

Comment: This is the best solution. It's the only answer that still lets you use strftime(), *and* combine padded and non padded elements, instead of either having all of them or none of them.

Answer (score 0):

"%l" (that's a lower-case L) works for the hour (instead of "%I"). I only
know this from another answer here

[Python strftime - date without leading 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904928/python-strftime-date-without-leading-0)

but unfortunately they don't have the code for the other elements of a date/time.

Comment: pd.to_datetime(dt['Time'], format= '%l:%M:%S', infer_datetime_format=True)
After try %l still not working for me
Error:- 
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 399, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_datetime_to_tsobject
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\np_datetime.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 09:15:59

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
D = str(datetime.now().day)
MM = str(datetime.now().month)
YYYY = str(datetime.now().year)
```

This, today, will return: 2, 12, 2021

Comment: Doesn't work properly for hours at midnight and after noon.

Answer (score 0):

In the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) formating section:

> 9. When used with the strptime() method, the leading zero is optional for formats %d, %m, %H, %I, %M, %S, %J, %U, %W, and %V. Format %y does require a leading zero.

So, using `%d` to parse day in number will automatically parse both `07` & `7` for example.

Comment: The question is for strftime(), to print the date as string. Not to parse from string using strptime().

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this for the first time, since I previously did most development work on linux exclusively. Here is my solution for an easy cross-platform approach on Python 3.8+

```py
from typing import AnyStr

import os

def unistrfmt(fmt: AnyStr) -> AnyStr:
    return fmt.replace(('%#', '%-')[os.name == 'nt'], ('%-', '%#')[os.name == 'nt'])

# Examples:

from datetime import date
date.today().strftime(unistrfmt("%Y.%m.%-d"))
# '2024.02.1'
os.name
#'nt'
unistrfmt("%Y.%m.%-d")
# '%Y.%m.%#d'
unistrfmt("%Y.%m.%#d")
# '%Y.%m.%#d'
```