# Python time formatting different in Windows

Tags: python, cross-platform

I'm probably missing an obvious platform difference that I should be accommodating but I'm getting this when trying to do a time format (Python2.7)...

in Linux env:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%a, %d-%b-%Y %T GMT", time.gmtime())
'Tue, 29-May-2012 21:42:04 GMT'
```

in Windows:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%a, %d-%b-%Y %T GMT", time.gmtime())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

The tuples returned from time.gmtime() appear to be the same, so I'm not completely sure what I need to change.

Comment: just to make sure, you are using the exact same versions of Python on both platforms?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In general, you'll find that python `time.strftime()` supports the same set of format specifiers as the platform (or that platform's libc to be more specific) it runs on. However, only a subset of these is portable. See http://docs.python.org/library/time.html for a list. To quote the docs:

> Additional directives may be supported on certain platforms, but only
>   the ones listed here have a meaning standardized by ANSI C.

In this case, `%T` can be replaced by `%H:%M:%S`.

Comment: Here is a list of format characters that are supported by the Windows strftime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx

Comment: A small gotcha: Linux/Posix/Unix `strftime` seems to silently ignore [some] invalid formatting, which cause Windows fatal exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `%T` format directive listed in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html?highlight=strftime#time.strftime) - must not be available/implemented for the Windows platform (I tried with both Python v2.7.3 and 3.2.3 just now)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had this problem because MacOS supports `"%D"` and I had to replace it with `"%m/%d/%Y"` to make it cross-platform.  In general, combining 'simple' format strings like `%m` seems to be safer than using 'aggregate' strings like `%T` or `%D`.