# Python Invalid format string

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to print the date in the following format using strftime:
06-03-2007 05:40PM

I have written the following code:

```
import time
print time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %T:%M%p")
```

But it gives an error "Invalid format string". Why is that?

Comment: working for me, it returns 10-01-2014 13:38:59:38PM

Comment: A minor point, the format you want `06-03-2007 05:40PM` is not the same as the format string you are using. You should use `"%m-%d-%Y %H:%I%p"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `hour`, `H` instead of `T`. check [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) possible options

```
print time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M%p")
```

**Note**:
The behavior is different on Windows and Linux machine. If you see what all are supported by Windows platform, check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx

So it is better to use `%H:%M:%S` than `%T` on Windows.

Comment: Yes this Worked! Thanx! I guess there is a problem with %T on Windows

Comment: Yes. For all the supported format options in Windows check the link I have put in my answer.

Comment: Excellent call on the difference between Windows and Linux.  Windows doesn't support "%-d" (day of month, no padding) and in fact has no option for that at all (the closest is "%e" (day of month, space padding).  This drove me crazy as I was testing on both and couldn't figure out why one was invalid.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The %T in:

```
print time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %T:%M%p")
```

Does not exsist. You should use %H (0-23) or %I (0-11)

Comment: It does: `>>> time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %T:%M%p") '10-01-2014 14:34:40:34PM'`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: I think it is a difference between Linux and Windows. Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807164/python-time-formatting-different-in-windows)

Comment: @Burhan which OS are you using?

Comment: I guess there is a problem with %T on Windows. %H worked!

Comment: Don't know why, but it indeed works on linux. Good job microsoft.

Comment: @ShaguftaOliveyuMethwani: use `%I` if you use `%p`