# How to convert date string by using Lib 'dateutil'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dateutil

When running `dateutil.parser.parse("2017-09-19T04:31:43Z").strftime('%s')` in Python, I obtain the following error:

> ValueError: Invalid format string

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same code works for me in Python 2.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
print(parse("2017-09-19T04:31:43Z").strftime('%s'))
# 1505813503
```

or

```
import dateutil.parser
print(dateutil.parser.parse("2017-09-19T04:31:43Z").strftime('%s'))
# 1505813503
```

---

#### The OP claims that this does NOT work, giving the same `ValueError: Invalid format string` error.

One explanation is that, according to this post, your option `%s` doesn't exist. See [valid options of `time.strftime` here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

#### Why did `%s` work on my system?

Great answer by Darren Stone from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801727/convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-and-convert-it-back-in-python)

> In the Python source for datetime and time, the string STRFTIME_FORMAT_CODES tells us:
>
> ```
> "Other codes may be available on your platform.
> See documentation for the C library strftime function."
> ```
>
> So now if we man strftime (on BSD systems such as Mac OS X), you'll find support for `%s`:
>
> ```
> %s is replaced by the number of seconds since the Epoch, UTC (see mktime(3))."
> ```

#### What can you do?

It seems you want the Unix timestamp. As suggested by @jleahy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743019/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch-with-strftime),

> If you want to convert a python datetime to seconds since epoch you
>   should do it explicitly:
>
> ```
> datetime.datetime(2012,04,01,0,0).strftime('%s') # '1333234800'
> (datetime.datetime(2012,04,01,0,0) - 
>  datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds() # 1333238400.0
> ```
>
> In Python 3.3+ you can use timestamp() instead:
>
> ```
> datetime.datetime(2012,4,1,0,0).timestamp() # 1333234800.0
> ```

Comment: So it seems that it doesn't work out in Python 3.5. I just don't know what goes wrong.

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140502/python-invalid-format-string), your option `%s` doesn't exist. I don't understand why it works for me, which prints the Unix time stamp. That's a good question I should ask. Anyway, check available options [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Comment: Very insightful! Let me check it out.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you simply typed it wrong. Maybe you meant to use uppercase S, which provides formatting for the seconds.  If not, %s as a format string is probably platform-specific.

If you look at [this page](http://strftime.org/), you'll see the comment:

> Platform specific directives: The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library's strftime() function, and platform variations are common.

For example, on Windows, %s (lowercase) is not accepted at all in strftime.
Windows, however, will recognize %S (uppercase) and treat the seconds as a zero-padded decimal number.

Another example of an incompatibility across platforms: Windows doesn't recognize hyphens in the format string, while it works on linux.  eg:

print(time.strftime("%-I:%M %p"))  #this fails on windows

Probably it's best for your code if you stick to the platform independent formatting string options mentioned here: http://strftime.org/