# Replace in a string representing a date only in certain positions

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string representing a date like: `yymmdd` (for example, `170901` for the 1st of September of 2017), obtained from a `datetime` object.

I want to replace the leading zeros of each field by a blank space. `str.replace()` won't do it it because it replaces the trailing zeros as well.

What would be the Pythonic way of substituting a character for another in a string but only in certain positions (in this case in the even indexes of the string)?

Comment: You said it yourself. *even* indexes.. The trailing ones are on the *odd* ones.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525944/python-datetime-formatting-without-zero-padding

Comment: Yes, I actually perform this action, but I'd like to see the best/most elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Since the `datetime` module does not provide an elegant way of doing what you want your request is very uncommon/rare (because `datetime` does almost everything with dates you could think of). So allow me to ask the question: Why do you want to do this, and do you really want to?

Comment: @timgeb Unfortunately, I do. I'm parsing files which use this ridiculous format, and I can't control it.

Comment: @timgeb Very true but even in the dupe you linked, the methods used are not from the `datetime` module. They are string manipulations (`lstrip`, `replace`).. In the accepted answer it even says, *"The formatting options available with datetime.strftime() will **all** zero-pad"*.

Comment: @user2891462 how do you wish `'000303'` to be parsed? Would it be `' 0 3 3'`?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Yes.

Comment: In either case, I would highly suggest you to use @MosesKoledoye's answer, as it doesn't rely on string manipulation, but works with actual dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to a `datetime` object, then use **formatting** to apply leading spaces instead of zeros to only month and day:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '170901'
s = '{dt:%y}{dt.month:2d}{dt.day:2d}'.format(dt=datetime.strptime(s, '%y%m%d'))
print(s)
#17 9 1
```

This also ensures that values outside the limits of days and months e.g 42, cannot be parsed.

From the `datetime` object, you can easily switch into whatever format you want or back-and-forth the initial and latter strings:

```
>>> '{dt:%y}{dt.month:02d}{dt.day:02d}'.format(dt=datetime.strptime(s, '%y%m%d'))
'170901'
>>> '{dt:%y} {dt:%b} {dt.day:2d}'.format(dt=datetime.strptime(s, '%y%m%d')) 
'17 Sep  1'
```

Comment: By far the best solution. `datetime` objects are way superior to playing around with strings, this allows you to do calculations with dates etc.

Comment: I have been using `datetime` until the very end, and `strftime` is actually how I got the string :)
I think this is the right answer, would you care to explain how the formatting in the third line of the first snippet works?

Comment: @user2891462 New style string formatting in Python supports formatting of datetime objects: https://pyformat.info/#datetime, and there's attribute access to treat some attributes specially: https://pyformat.info/#getitem_and_getattr. Combine both and you have a *powerful* tool for formatting `datetime` objects.

Comment: Ah, I see now! `dt.month` is an integer, which gets formatted to 2 spaces with `{dt.month:02d}`. This is very clever, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Would you consider this an *elegant* way of doing it?

```
s = '170901'    
res = ''.join([' ' if i%2==0 and x=='0' else x for i, x in enumerate(s)])
print(res)  # 17 9 1
```

---

You can also create a function out of it for easier use:

```
def date_format(date_as_str):
    return ''.join([' ' if i%2==0 and x=='0' else x for i, x in enumerate(date_as_str)])

print(date_format('170901'))  # 17 9 1
print(date_format('170910'))  # 17 910  does not remove the trailing ones..
```

Comment: Yes, this one-liner suits my needs :) I'll wait a day or so to see if I get an answer I like more and otherwise accept yours.

Comment: I have accepted @MosesKoledoye answer because it fits my particular case better. I have upvoted yours as well since it is a good approach to more general cases.

Comment: @user2891462 No worries. Mose's way is the better way anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, with some iteration magic to avoid building unnecessary containers. But also note my comment.

```
>>> from itertools import izip, chain
>>> date = '170901'
>>> ''.join((chain.from_iterable((x if x != '0' else ' ', y) for x,y in izip(*[iter(date)]*2))))
'17 9 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be able to be shortened however; you could try and use the `datetime` module.

```
import datetime

date_str = "170901"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%y%m%d")
space_date = ''.join([x.rjust(2) for x in [date.strftime("%y").lstrip('0'), str(date.month), str(date.day)]])

print(space_date) #17 9 1
```