# How to troubleshoot a python UDF in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I wrote a simple UDF in python for PIG

```
@outputSchema("date: chararray")
def to_date2(dt):
  print dt
  a = dt.split("/")
  print a
  return "20" + a[2] + a[0] + a[1]
```

I am reading a CSV which has a column like "1/1/17" and I am trying to convert it into `201711` using this UDF.

I get an error

```
Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "/tmp/pig715837049480092569tmp/util2.py", line 20, in to_date2 
 IndexError: index out of range: 2
```

but I can't see any of my print statements in the job run log.

If I am writing a python UDF how to I print things into the Hadoop log? so that I can see what was the value of dt which was passed to my function?

Comment: You would look at the YARN (or Tez) UI for your job output. The real solution is to put a try catch in your code, though

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you should use `strptime` to parse dates, not split

```
from datetime import date
dt = date.strptime(dt, '%d/%m/%y')
return dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

If you want to remove the leading zeros (which you should keep, or at least keep some delimiter to avoid 201711 being parsed as `Nov 2017`), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9526118/2308683)

Comment: yes. that's fine. but how do I perform printing into Hadoop logs?

Comment: As mentioned in comments above. It's in the YARN UI port 8088 of the ResourceManager. You could also use Pig to dump your CSV column as-is in order to debug it. Pig also has string splitting and date parsing functions