# How to convert date to lose leading zero from Month in DatetTime Library Robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

I have below code

```
${d}=    Get Current Date    result_format=%m/%d/%Y
log  ${d}
```

and the output is

> 06/14/2018

In my expecation i want

> 6/14/2018

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
${d}=    Get Current Date    result_format=%#m/%d/%Y
log  ${d}
```

Use '#' in-front of month to get rid of zero. Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525944/python-datetime-formatting-without-zero-padding)

Note that this is platform-dependent; for Unix (Linux/MacOS), you'll need to use a hyphen instead:

`%Y/%-m/%-d`