# Robotframework - Day of the month without zero-padded decimal number

Tags: robotframework

I use this:

```
${today}=  Get Time
${today_formated}=  Convert Date  ${today}  result_format=%d
```

The result is `01` for the 1st day of the month but I need **1**.

- %d [is Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.  01, 02, …, 31](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

How to remove **0** at the start?

My question is on the **day of the month** not on the month number

**full robotframework script:**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    DateTime

*** Keywords ***
test
    ${today}=           Get Time
    ${today_formated}=  Convert Date      ${today}  result_format=%d
    Log To Console  ${today_formated}

*** Test Cases ***

PLFT
    [Tags]  foo|AC0
    Given test
```

> 01

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python datetime formatting without zero-padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525944/python-datetime-formatting-without-zero-padding)

Comment: @TodorMinakov, No, my question is on the day of the month not on the month number. Please revove duplucate tag.

Comment: It's the same, is it the day of the month or the month number - simple string manipulation.

Comment: Your question is - how to remove the 0-padding of dates produced by `strftime()`; the linked question has numerous answers, some good, some less so. Thus I marked it as a duplicate. "Würgspaß find the solution, not you." I'm truly happy for him, thus he got my upvote ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. And in the same time, I find the tone of your message inappropriate.

Comment: @TodorMinakov, my question is not "how to remove the 0-padding of dates produced by strftime();" is it "**Day of the month** without zero-padded decimal number"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Replace String Using Regexp` from standard library `String`

```
${today}=  Get Time
${today_formated}=  Convert Date  ${today}  result_format=%d
${today_no_padding}=    Replace String Using Regexp    ${today_formated}    ^0    ${EMPTY}
```

This transforms values with leading zeros like `01` to `1` but values just containing zeros like `10` would remain the same.

To use the library, add a declaration to your settings:

```
*** Settings ***
    Library    SeleniumLibrary
    Library    DateTime
    Library    String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use '#' during format to ignore 0's e.g.

```
${today}=  Get Time

${today_formated}=  Convert Date  ${today}  result_format=%#d
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use # in front of the date variable
For Example:
%#m/%#d/%#Y