# Changing date format from year month day

Tags: python, date

Using the following  to calculate today's date.
    import datetime

```
today = datetime.date.today()
print(today)
```

It returns the date in format of **2020-04-08**
However I need it in the format of **4/8/20**

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: The datetime documentation includes all of this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python datetime formatting without zero-padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525944/python-datetime-formatting-without-zero-padding)

Comment: If at all possible, consider *not* doing this. the ISO 8601 YYYY-MM-DD format is standard and unambiguous and has numerous advantages over M/D/YY. Among other issues, "4/8/20" will be interpreted as April 8 in the US and as August 4 in the UK -- and, depending on the context might refer to the year 1920 rather than 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-` to remove the leading zeros from day and month:

```
from datetime import date

d = date.today().strftime("%-m/%-d/%y")
print(d)
```

If you use Windows, change the format string to `"%#m/%#d/%y"`

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA are you sure? It works perfect on my machine (python3.7+): https://repl.it/repls/FreeLooseMoto

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Right! In Windows it's a bit different. I've updated my solution. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y")
print(today)
```

Comment: The OP said "*I need it in the format of 4/8/20*". Your code will print it as 04-08-20.