# Only show relevant time units in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, strftime

I have a program that outputs flight time but sometimes it's less than an hour and in that case I don't want a 0 hour displayed.

I could use an `if` statement for one that has hours and one that doesn't but that doesn't seem efficient. Also would be nice if minutes is zero don't display minutes either.

```
landed_time_msg = time.strftime("Apx. flt. time %-H Hours : %-M Mins. ",time.gmtime(self.landed_time))
```

Comment: Does this post help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525944/python-datetime-formatting-without-zero-padding

Comment: Is dt.strftime("Apx. flt. time %-H Hours : %-M Mins. ").replace("0","").replace("  Hours :","").replace(" 1 Hours"," 1 Hour").replace(" :  Mins","").replace(" 1 Mins"," 1 Min") fine?

Comment: Yes those work thanks!