# How to compare and parse out NaN values in rows of a DataFrame in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare two values in the same row to eachother to see which is greater.  The two rows are dates like this:

```
PheneVisit  PheneDate   ER Date
phchp010v3  9/22/06 
phchp010v3  9/22/06     5/1/20
phchp101v1  9/14/09 
phchp101v1  9/14/09
```

And I want to put the highest value in a new column called "dates" using the code below, but it does not catch the blank/NaN values for the ER Date column and simply produces more NaN columns if there is no ER Date.

Here is the code I have currently:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if (pd.to_datetime(row['PheneDate']) > pd.to_datetime(row['ER Date'])) or (row['ER Date'] == 0):
        print('1')
        data["date order"] = data['PheneDate']
    elif pd.to_datetime(row['ER Date']) > pd.to_datetime(row['PheneDate']) or [row['PheneDate'] == 0]:
        print(2)
        data["date order"] = data['ER Date']
```

which produces the following output:

```
date order

5/1/20
```

The desired output would be

```
9/22/06
5/1/20
9/14/09
9/14/09
```

**
I simply need to check the values for NaN in each cell and if it is empty then the non empty date should be taken.  I also tried == 'nan' and == 0
**

Comment: check if its just blank that is try == ''

Comment: @darthbaba sadly this did not work either. I've tried many things such ```as or (data['ER Date'][index] == "NaN")``` and "nan" as well as .isnull.any() When I print the empty cell, i get nan and for type i get float, which is why I tried == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert to the datetime type and use normal comparison:

```
df['PheneDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PheneDate'])
df['ER'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ER'])
df['Date'] = df[['PheneDate', 'ER']].max(axis=1)
```

output:

```
   PheneVisit  PheneDate         ER       Date
0  phchp010v3 2006-09-22        NaT 2006-09-22
1  phchp010v3 2006-09-22 2020-05-01 2020-05-01
2  phchp101v1 2009-09-14        NaT 2009-09-14
3  phchp101v1 2009-09-14        NaT 2009-09-14
```

If you need to convert back to string with a specific regional formatting, use the following:

```
>>> df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')

0    09/22/06
1    05/01/20
2    09/14/09
3    09/14/09
```

Finally, if you really want to [avoid leading zeros in the month/day formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29980406/16343464):

```
>>> df['Date'].dt.strftime('%-m/%-d/%y')

0    9/22/06
1     5/1/20
2    9/14/09
3    9/14/09
```

Comment: perfect, I guess I was over doing it with the iterrows and all that, however I thought what I had would work anyway. I guess not. Thank you!

Comment: It is very often more efficient and more concise to use vector operation rather than manually iterating over the rows.

Comment: is what you provided a vector operation?

Comment: The [pandas.DataFrame.max](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) is vectorized

Answer (score 0):

Try numpy where:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['ER Date'] > df['PheneDate'], df['ER Date'], df['PheneDate'])
```