# Pandas datetime, converting monthly date to month end day

Tags: pandas

Trying to get end of month data with datetime.

my code:

```
monthyear = input("Enter Full Month and Year: ")   #Ie September 2021
assessdate = pd.to_datetime(prevdate, format="%B %Y").strftime('%m%d%Y %H:%M')
```

getting

```
09012021 00:00
```

expecting:

```
09/30/2021 00:00
```

tried:

```
monthyear = input("Enter Full Month and Year: ")   #Ie September 2021
assessdate = pd.to_datetime(monthyear, format="%B %Y")+MonthEnd(1).dt.strftime('%m%d%Y %H:%M')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a few issues:

1. We only want to `strftime` once we have the entire date resolved. For this reason we need parenthesis around our offset computation.
2. `MonthEnd(1)` is not generally what we want to get the end of the current month. We want `MonthEnd(0)`
3. The format string is missing `/`

All together it can look like:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

month_year = input("Enter Full Month and Year: ")  # Ie September 2021
assess_date = (
        pd.to_datetime(month_year, format="%B %Y") + MonthEnd(0)
).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
print(assess_date)
```

Program input/ouptut:

```
Enter Full Month and Year: September 2021
09/30/2021 00:00
```

---

The difference between `MonthEnd(1)` and `MonthEnd(0)` is that if it is the last day of the month the result will be different:

```
pd.Timestamp('2021-09-30') + MonthEnd(1)  # 2021-10-31 00:00:00
pd.Timestamp('2021-09-30') + MonthEnd(0)  # 2021-09-30 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to strip that `0` before the `09`?

Comment: Add `#` or `-` before the Month pattern depending on operating system. For windows (`'%#m/%d/%Y %H:%M'`) or for linux/mac (`'%-m/%d/%Y %H:%M'`) [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42709606/15497888)