# Python datetime format string excluding zeros

Tags: python, string, python-datetime

```
str(datetime.date.today())
```

I get: `2023-04-01`

I need: `2023-4-1`

If I format it to remove zeros then I will face an issue if the date is `2023-10-20`

How can I do it quick and simple. I need it as a string.

Comment: What is wrong with `2023-10-20`?

Comment: nothing wrong with 2023-10-20 (Its just an example I mentioned), The question is regarding converting 2023-04-01 to 2023-4-1

Comment: Your question literally states "then I will face an issue if the date is 2023-10-20". Have you even looked at the `datetime` module in python for formatting?

Comment: between I have checked datetime model I didn't see anything regarding what I need.

Comment: I'm going to ignore all of that (millions of people move between countries) but there is no directive to get the format you want in the base [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) it seems. I'm not sure why you need this format in the first place

Comment: Another duplicate: [Python datetime formatting without zero-padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525944/python-datetime-formatting-without-zero-padding)

Comment: @roganjosh I am building a boat that runs using code instead of fuel, and the best part the speakers sing dolphins and whales. Thnx

Comment: @LercDsgn Tack så mycket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
formatted_date = today.strftime("%Y-%-m-%-d")
print(formatted_date)
```

Comment: note `%-` directives are platform-specific, for instance they don't work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can always format yourself, since the `datetime` module doesn't appear to have a portable way to do it:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> d=dt.date.today()
>>> f'{d.year}-{d.month}-{d.day}'
'2023-4-1'
```