# How do I write the hour of the time without a leading zero or leading space?

Tags: ruby, time, ruby-1.9, strftime, time-format

In a Ruby 1.9 program, I want to format the current time like `Thu 1:51 PM`. What format code should I use for the hour of the day (`1` in this example)?

```
Time.now.strftime '%a %I:%M %p' #=> "Thu 01:51 PM"
Time.now.strftime '%a %l:%M %p' #=> "Thu  1:51 PM"
```

`%I` has a leading zero (`01`). `%l` has a leading space ( `1`). I don’t see any other format code for the hour in the [strftime documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime). I can’t use `.lstrip` because the space is in the middle of the string. I could use `.gsub(/ +/, " ")`, but I’m wondering if there’s a less hacky, simpler way.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
Time.now.strftime '%a %-l:%M %p' #=> "Thu 1:51 PM"
```

Write `%-l` instead of `%l`. The `-` strips leading spaces and zeroes.

You can use `-` with the other format codes, too. The Ruby strftime documentation even mentions `%-m` and `%-d`, though it fails to mention that you can use `-` with any code. Thus, `%-I` would give the same result as `%-l`. But I recommend `%-l`, because using `l` instead of `I` signifies to me that that you don’t want anything at the beginning – the space it writes looks more accidental.

You can also see [an exhaustive list of Ruby **1.8** `strftime` format codes](http://lostincode.net/blog/strtime-ruby-osx), including ones with `-` and the similar syntaxes `_` and `0`. It says that Ruby 1.8 on Mac OS X doesn’t support those extended syntaxes, but don’t worry: they work in Ruby 1.9 on my OS X machine.

Comment: Wish every solution was this simple and straightforward. +1

Comment: This solution might work only on Unix systems, not on Windows. [This answer to “Python `strftime`
 – date without leading 0?”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2073189/578288) is about the same task in Python, and says that `%-` only works on Unix. [Why does “%-d”, or “%-e” remove the leading space or zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28894172/578288) says that the incompatibility is because Python calls the underlying operator system’s `strftime`, which may have platform-specific extensions. I don’t know if Ruby’s `strftime` is the same.