# datetime.strptime formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

My datetime in my CSV file is like the following:

```
2011/1/1 0:00
2011/1/1 0:30
2011/1/1 1:00
```

when I run:

```
date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

I get datetime output as:

```
[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 30)]
```

How can i format it to the original datetime?

Comment: Hint: `strptime` and `strftime` take the same format strings. One is for parsing, the other if for formatting.

Comment: `date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')`

Answer (score 2):

You have already parsed a string into a datetime object. This is done by using `datetime.datetime.strptime()`. To format the object back into a string you can use the same syntax but using method `datetime.datetime.strftime()`, e.g.:

```
date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

See also [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

If you want *exactly* your input string (without leading 0), you can put a hyphen between percentage operator and directive character where necessary, e.g.:

```
date.strftime('%Y/%-m/%-d %-H:%M')
```

This is well explained in: [Python strftime - date without leading 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/904928/2648551) but it is [platform dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28916983/2648551).

Answer (score 1):

Try printing date in string format:

```
from datetime import datetime    

row = "2011/1/1 0:30"
date = datetime.strptime(row, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
print str(date)
```

output:

```
'2011-01-01 00:30:00'
```

Comment: OK. i get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is creating a datetime object from a string and formatter as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). Likely somewhere in your code you put this object in a list and referenced it. Python doesn't know that you want to print the container(the list) with it in a certain string format.

If I'm understanding your question you want to print/return the element and not the container. Shown below:

```
import datetime

l = []
today = datetime.date.today()
l.append(today)
#what you have
print(l)
#addressing just the first element
print(l[0])
```