# Format string for date invalid when converting to decimal day and month

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Specifically I am having problems with using `%-d` and `%-m` on Windows.

The error I am getting is simple

```
output_dict.update({"DOB1": f"{dob.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y') if not dob is None else 'UniqueID' + str(row)}"})
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

My format string looks like this:

```
dob.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y')
```

I am fairly certain that this is because I am windows but I was wondering if there was a platform independent way of fixing this problem or if I am doing something else wrong which is causing this error.

I saw something about `%e` being used for the month in windows `strftime` but it replaces the 0 with a space instead but this is undesirable. I am trying to get these exact outputs (I use a similar format string later) `1/1/2000` and `January 1 2000`.

I would prefer not to use a solution like `{dob.year}` ect because I already have a format string that this is being placed in.

I would appreciate any ideas surrounding best practices and how I can implement a solution to this. Thank you.

Comment: can you show what is in your varialbe dob

Comment: Use a `#` instead of a `-` on Windows, as said there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894172/why-does-d-or-e-remove-the-leading-space-or-zero#comment96325960_28916983

Comment: @jona that solved the problem could you flesh it out into a full answer for future readers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A part of the answer is buried in this SA comment : [Why does "%-d", or "%-e" remove the leading space or zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894172/why-does-d-or-e-remove-the-leading-space-or-zero#comment96325960_28916983)

On Windows, you should use `#` to avoid the zero-padding (it replaces the `-` on Unix systems).

Here is a small example :

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime(2015, 3, 5).strftime('%d')
'05'
>>> datetime(2015, 3, 5).strftime('%-d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid format string
>>> datetime(2015, 3, 5).strftime('%#d')
'5'
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a cross-platform solution.