# Why do platform inconsistencies with datetime.strftime exist?

Tags: python, datetime-format, python-datetime

According to https://strftime.org, the format code `%-m` (as well as a bunch of others) is marked as "Platform dependent". The specifier `%-m` means "month as a decimal". This seems like a very basic function, so how/why does it vary across operating systems?  If I parse "1", what platform could run into issues with this? Finally, what platforms are we talking about? Does this vary by OS?

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK they only work in linux, not windows

Comment: The answer is just a bit further down on the same page.  Ctrl+f for the section titled "*Platform specific directives*"

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Thank you both!

Comment: [related, SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894172/why-does-d-or-e-remove-the-leading-space-or-zero), and also pointed out in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) - *Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common* .