# Trying to convert a date to another format gives error

Tags: python, date

I have a program where the user selects a date from a datepicker, and I need to convert this date to another format.

The original format is `%d/%m/%Y` and I need to convert it to `%-d-%b-%Y`.

I made a small example of what happens:

```
from datetime import datetime
# Import tkinter library
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

win = Tk()
win.geometry("750x250")
win.title("Example")


def convert():
    date1 = cal.get()
    datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(date1, '%d/%m/%Y')
    print(date1)
    new_format = datetimeobject.strftime('%-d-%b-%Y')
    print(new_format)


cal = DateEntry(win, width=16, background="gray61", foreground="white", bd=2, date_pattern='dd/mm/y')
cal.pack(pady=20)

btn = Button(win, command=convert, text='PRESS')
btn.pack(pady=50)

win.mainloop()
```

This gives me the following error:

```
  File "---------\date.py", line 15, in convert
    new_format = datetimeobject.strftime('%-d-%b-%Y')
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Comment: Your target date format string is faulty. Try `%d-%b-%Y` (without the extra dash). And did you mean `%b` or `%m`?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why that gives an error is because `%-d` only works on Unix machines (Linux, MacOS). On Windows (or Cygwin), you have to use `%#d`.

Comment: This link can also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904928/python-strftime-date-without-leading-0

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to the use of the `%-d` format specifier in the `strftime()` method. This specifier is not supported in the Windows platform.

To resolve this issue, you can replace the `%-d` format specifier with `%d` and remove the `-`.

Comment: Oh indeed, you're right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894172/why-does-d-or-e-remove-the-leading-space-or-zero

Comment: Hi, Qbasix!  Several of your recent answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.