# Python Datetime Formatted as "1/1/1990"

Tags: python, datetime

In python how would I format the date as 1/1/1990?

> dayToday = datetime.date(1990,1,1)
>   print dayToday

This returns 1990-01-01, but I want it to look like 1/1/1990. (Jan 1 1990)

Comment: that is how sane people store their dates. :)

Comment: @MattBall Not a duplicate if OP cares about leading `0`.

Comment: @mgilson Combined, it's a duplicate, but I'm not sure it's applicable when neither of those answers OP separately on both how to format from a date, and to fix leading `0`. Flag it if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look into python [datetime.strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
dayToday = datetime.date(1990,1,1) 
print dayToday.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
>>> 1990/01/01
print dayToday.strftime('%Y/%b/%d')
>>> 1990/Jan/01
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`datetime.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) function with an appropriate [format string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print now.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
2013/04/19
```

Comment: Not the format OP asked for. Both regarding leading `0` and order of dates.

Answer (score 0):

Others have showed how to get the output `1990/01/01`, but assuming you don't want the leading zeros in there, the only way that I know of to do it is to do the string formatting yourself:

```
>>> '{dt.year}/{dt.month}/{dt.day}'.format(dt = dt.datetime.now())
'2013/4/19'
```

Answer (score 0):

With the correct format **and** a without leading `0`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime("%-m/%-d/%Y")
'4/19/2013'
```

Reported to [only work for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904928/python-strftime-date-without-leading-0), but I haven't tested anything else personally.
Tested and working for `2.7.3` and `3.2.3` on Linux x64.

Comment: Are you sure?  This gives me:  `'-m/-d/2013'`.  Maybe platform specific?  (I'm using OS-X)

Comment: @mgilson It seems it's a Linux-only.

Comment: Tested on my linux machine and it works there.  Which makes me feel good.  I was trying stuff like this before I finally came up with the answer I did and none of it worked.  Now I know why :)