# Can I operate on formatted strings?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

A snippet of Python code:

```
def someMethod():
    return datetime.date.today().strftime("%B" + " " + "%d".lstrip('0') + ", " + "%Y")
```

How come this returns:

```
June 03, 2015
```

And not what I expected, which was:

```
June 3, 2015
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python strftime - date without leading 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904928/python-strftime-date-without-leading-0)

Comment: @Andy: I debated it with myself, but in the end decided the fundamental misunderstanding in the question (stripping `"%d"`) warrants a separate answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"%d".lstrip('0')` is `"%d"`, as `"%d"` never had any zeroes in it to begin with. If you are asking if you can operate on different parts formatted by `strftime`, the answer is no. But you can influence formatting precision.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16097385/240443) for a good alternative, and [this answer on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2073189/240443) for another, possibly non-portable alternative.