# How to add variables together into a new variable where you control the separation

Tags: python

Let's say i've declared three variables which are a date, how can I combine them into a new variable where i can print them in the correct 1/2/03 format by simply printing the new variable name.

```
month = 1
day = 2
year = 03

date = month, day, year  <<<<< What would this code have to be? 

print(date)
```

I know i could set the sep='/' argument in the print statement if i call all three variables individually, but this means i can't add addition text into the print statement without it also being separated by a /. therefore i need a single variable i can call.

Comment: Note that your month, day, and year variables should be strings (e.g. `year = '03'`; otherwise the leading zero will be dropped.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for asking a good question: you showed us what you've tried so far, and explained what you were trying to do. While you're here, I suggest taking the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). And don't forget to "**accept**" whichever answer you find most useful, so that others who find your question later will know which answer solved your problem. To accept an answer, click on the checkmark below the answer's score, and the checkmark will turn green. (Note that you can only accept one answer per question.)

Comment: According to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) `1/2/03` isn't the correct format. ;-)

Comment: @dimo414 - Actually, it's better to use integers for months, days and years, because you can't do math on strings. You should only convert them to strings (with something like `str.format()`) when you're ready to print them out.

Comment: You *definitely* should not treat dates as integers if you're intending to do math.  Use the appropriate date libraries for date arithmetic.  If OP just wants to print a numeric value with a leading zero, they should use strings.

Answer (score 5):

The [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method does what you want (assuming the input is strings):

```
>>> '/'.join((month, day, year))
1/2/03
```

As does all of Python's [formatting options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452/113632), e.g.:

```
>>> '%s/%s/%s' % (month, day, year)
1/2/03
```

But date formatting (and working with dates in general) is tricky, and there are existing tools to do it "right", namely the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html) module, see [`date.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

```
>>> date = datetime.date(2003, 1, 2)
>>> date.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
'01/02/03'
>>> date.strftime('%-m/%-d/%y')
'1/2/03'
```

Note the `-` before the `m` and the `d` to [suppress leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2073189/113632) on the month and date.

Comment: Good idea pointing him to `datetime`. I think he should also look into [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), as that's something every Python beginner should learn about.

Comment: Your `.join` method seems to be more magic than mine, because mine is complaining about "expected string, int found" (Trivially fixed with `'/'.join(map(str,(month,day,year)))`)

Comment: You can't use ints to represent strings with leading zeros - see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method. You can also use a list comprehension to format the strings so they are each 2 digits wide.

```
>>> '/'.join('%02d' % i for i in [month, day, year])
'01/02/03'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to read about the `str.format()` method:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Or if you're using Python 2:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

The `join()` function will also work in this case, but learning about `str.format()` will be more useful to you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* answer is: use the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime

month = 1
day = 2
year = 2003

date = datetime(year, month, day)
print(date)
print(date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))

# etc
```

Trying to handle dates as tuples is just a PITA, so don't waste your time.