# strptime removing 0 from month and not being recognised by %m

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

The following is my code which i am running on a dataframe

```
def get_day_limit(self):
    self.df['day_end'] = np.where(self.df.index == self.df.index.get_loc(dt.strptime(str(self.df.index.date),'%Y-%m-%d')+' '+'15:15:00'),1,0)
```

The index date and time format is as follows

```
2020-02-18 09:15:00

2020-02-18 09:30:00

2020-02-18 09:45:00
```

When the time is equal to 15:15:00 irrespective of the date, i want the `self.df['day_end']` to be 1 else 0

but i get the following error:-

```
> ValueError: time data '[datetime.date(2020, 2, 18) datetime.date(2020,
> 2, 18)\n datetime.date(2020, 2, 18) ... datetime.date(2020, 5, 20)\n
> datetime.date(2020, 5, 20) datetime.date(2020, 5, 20)]' does not match
> format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

When i had tried it separately, i noticed that the 0 is removed from the month `datetime.date` because of which it is unable to read month with `%m`

i search stack overflow and found that, when we use `%Y-%m-%d` format with a hyphen, it removes the zero in the start. Here [Python strftime - date without leading 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904928/python-strftime-date-without-leading-0).

BUT MY DATA WILL ONLY BE AVAILABLE WITH HYPHEN.

i tried using `.date()` but ndarray is non callable object

Comment: Because you've probably passed the entire Series to your function, but you didn't show that

Comment: What do you get printing `self.df.index`?

Comment: DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-18 09:15:00', '2020-02-18 09:30:00',
               '2020-02-18 09:45:00', '2020-02-18 10:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=1495, freq=None)

Comment: i did add the entire series but np where is iterating through the rows one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
def get_day_limit(df):
    if (df.index.hour==15) & (df.index.minute==15):
       df['day_end'] = 1
    else:
       df['day_end'] = 0
```

Comment: It gives me the following error
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'hours'

Comment: @KunthuDhadda should be just `df['day_end'] = (s.hour==15) & (s.minute=15)`.

Comment: This code worked for me. i changed the hours to hour and minutes to minute
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can just use `time` to extract the time and compare:

```
# NOT the common `from datetime import datetime`
import datetime

def get_day_limit(self):
    self.df['day_end'] = (self.df.index.time == datetime.time(15,15)).astype(int)
```

Or another way without extra package:

```
def get_day_limit(self):
    time = self.df.index - self.df.index.normalize()
    self.def['day_end'] = (time==pd.to_timedelta('15:15:00')).astype(int)
```

Comment: This gave me the following error
TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'

Comment: @KunthuDhadda try the second approach, or my comment under the other answer.

Comment: and also, it's just `import datetime`, not `from datetime import datetime`. They are two different things.

Comment: @KunthuDhadda: QuangHoang's solution works fine for me, your issue seems to be related to df.index. make sure it is dtype='datetime64[ns]' when you call the method in your class