# how to get D instated of DD from DD-MM-YYYY format if day = 01 to 09 then output should be 1 to 9

Tags: python, datetime

Output I got = January 01, 2023

But required Output = January 1, 2023

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("380x220")
midate = datetime.date(2020,1,1)
cal1 = DateEntry(root, selectmode='day')
cal1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=30)

def my_upd():
print(cal1.get_date().strftime("%B %d, %Y"))

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Read', command=lambda:my_upd())
b1.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If your platform supports it, you may be able to use `%e` - `.strftime("%B%e, %Y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange that there's no format code for a non-padded day of the month.  But you can put it together piece wise and remove the leading zero.

```
d = cal1.get_date()
print(d.strftime("%B ") + d.strftime("%d").lstrip("0") + d.strftime(", %Y"))
```

You could do the same thing and not bother with `strftime` for the day:

```
print(d.strftime("%B ") + str(d.day) + d.strftime(", %Y"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you go to the official python documentation, you will not find any formatting for `day` without leading zeros.

The only way you can remove these zeros is by simply using python's `replace()` string method.

```
import datetime

midate = datetime.date(2020,1,1)

def my_upd():
    print(midate.strftime("%B %d, %Y").replace(' 0', ' '))

my_upd()
```

Output:

```
January 1, 2020
```

Some platforms will support `%e`, but if your application wants to run in all circumstances, you will have to follow the safe steps.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered in the link below.
[Python strftime - date without leading 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904928/python-strftime-date-without-leading-0)

If you want to get detailed information about Python date formatting, I recommend you to look at the following document.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes